# replace windows cmd call to .bat for and web based GUI?

Tags: javascript

to upload new changes into our server i have to type something like

```
uploadTemplates.bat templateid userid password integrationorProductionVar + ENTER
```

Thas fine but first i need to navigate to the folder where the .bat is,

Question is: can i change all this for a more automatized GUI?? if so, how?

for example a Form asking

user, pass, templateid and integrationorPrdoductionVar (as a select) and it opens the .bat on the background ?

Comment: Yes, you can. Try Visual Basic if you must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could do it in PHP if the PHP server runs on the machine where the .bat file is. In order to call a shell command, you can use [`system`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php):

```
system("uploadTemplates.bat {$_POST['templateid']} {$_POST['userid']} {$_POST['password']} {$_POST['integrationorProductionVar']}");
```

Note that since this should run on the same system and is only to be used by you, you can get away with not sanitize your data, but normally, you want to escape your shell arguments with [`escapeshellarg`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) and do as much checking as possible so that someone can't exploit this and run malicious commands on the system.

Comment: sorry i didn't that this .bat is executed locally in windows.. i guess this is not going to work for us... thanks dough

Comment: Yes, so just run an Apache server in local on your Windows

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming by this question you don't have much in the way of coding experience. JavaScript isn't a language that'll be much use for this.

Download yourself a copy of Visual Express and depending on how brave you're feeling, download either Visual Basic or C# and look at a couple of tutorials.

What you're after is very basic to implement and even without any experience at all would take you under an hour to create I reckon.